# try_files and sub-locations

Tags: file, nginx, url-rewriting, try-catch

If the last option of a try_files contains a uri that matches a sub-location will that location get called?

```
location /some/path {
  alias /a/mount/point;
  try_files $uri /some/path/index.php$is_args$args;

  location ~ \.php {
    fastcgi_pass  phpfpm;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include       fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
  }
}
```

In the above example would try_files /some/path/index.php hit the ~ .php sub location?

Comment: Yes. Although there are [some open issues](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) regarding use of `alias` with `try_files`.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that if the URI has arguments it either doesn't pass through to php_fpm or if I try and include $is_args$args in the try_files it seems to go searching for other locations blocks.